# String function in php which cuts string like fread()

Tags: php, string

I know, for someone it is simple, but I am quite new to php. I need simple loop where is some php function which cut part of string like fread.

```
while ($part = fread($fh, 100)) {
    echo $part."<br>";
}
```

My dream loop will looks like

```
$string = "hello";    
while ($part = some_function($string, 2)) {
            echo $part."<br>";
 }
```

and output will be

```
he
ll
o
```

Thanks

Comment: You need it to do what the above code does...so, then, what's wrong with the code you have?  Please explain a little more about the data, and why what you have here isn't what you want and what needs to be different about it.  You gave us very little to go on other than that it should read strings and echo them.

Comment: Wow, somebody hated all of the answers!

Comment: me not, I dont have enought points guys. I would like to add one point for all answers.

Comment: haters gonna hate. but im glad you found a solution anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much easier:

```
$string = "hello";    
foreach(str_split($string, 2) as $part) {
    echo $part."<br>";
}
```

If you really want a while loop:

```
$parts = str_split($string, 2);
while($part = current($parts)) {
    echo $part."<br>";
    next($parts);
}
```

Or to not split into an array:

```
$i = 0;
$string = "hello";    
while($part = substr($string, $i, 2)) {
    echo $part."<br>";
    $i=$i+2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should behave similar to your code, but for strings.

```
$offset = 0;
$part = '';
do {
    $part = substr($content, $offset * 100, 100);
    echo($part);
    $offset++;
} while (strlen($part) > 0);
```

**#Edit 1:**

In case you are working with special characters like `ÜÄÖ` you will need to use the `mb_substr`-function.

[PHP: substr - Manual](https://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) ,
[PHP: mb_substr - Manual](https://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php)

**#Edit 2:**

Version for your dream-loop:

```
$content = "hello";

$offset = 0;
$part = '';
do {
    $part = substr( $content, $offset * 2, 2 );
    echo( $part . '<br>' );
    $offset++;
} while ( strlen( $part ) > 0 );
```

Comment: fixed the substr-syntax

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use the prag_match function with regex.
It will take a pattern, and checks the string for matches. 
You can write out only the matches.
I hope it is what you are looking for.

Here is a link to the manual of the function:
[enter link description here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)